# making a dynamic queue in C++

Tags: c++, queue

I'm trying to make a dynamic **queue** in C++ and I wrote most of the code, yet it doesn't work, could someone be kind enough to look through it and tell me what's wrong? :)
Also please comment on the coding style I wish to improve.

I wrote a main function to test the program and this should be the expected result:

data1=1

data1=1 data2=2

1 2 3 4 5 6

Del:1 Del:2 Del:3

### This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
class Queue
{
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int qsize;

public:
    Queue()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        qsize = 0;
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        if(qsize = 0){return true;}
        else         {return false;}
    }

    void put(const T& data)
    {    
        Node *newNode = new Node;
        if(qsize)
        {
            tail->next = newNode;
            newNode->data = data;
            newNode->next = NULL;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            head = tail = newNode;
            newNode->data = data;
            newNode->next = NULL;
        }
        qsize++;
    }

    T get()
    {
        T val;
        Node *temp;

        if(empty())
        {
            std::cout << "queue is empty" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            val = head->data;
            temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;

            qsize--;
            return val;
        }
    }

    void destroyQueue()
    {
        while(!empty())
        {
            std::cout<<"DEL:";
            get();
        }
    }

    ~Queue()
    {
        destroyQueue();
    }
};



int main()
{
    int data1,data2;
    Queue<int>* q = new Queue<int>();
    q->put(1);
    data1 = q->get();
    std::cout << " data1=" << data1 << std::endl;
    q->put(1);
    q->put(2);
    data1 = q->get();
    data2 = q->get();
    std::cout << " data1=" << data1
              << " data2=" << data2 << std::endl;
    q->put(1);
    q->put(2);
    q->put(3);
    q->put(4);
    q->put(5);
    q->put(6);
    while (!q->empty()) std::cout << " " << q->get();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    q->put(1);
    q->put(2);
    q->put(3);
    delete q;
}
```

Comment: Basic compiler warnings should tell you the mistake.

Comment: First thing I noticed is the wrong Equality operator in bool empty().         if(qsize == 0)

Comment: must have everseen that! so embarrising!

Answer (score 1):

`if(qsize = 0)` should be `if(qsize == 0)` - don't **assign**, compare!